# Как называется та часть от стоимости, которая остаётся после скидки?

Tags: одним-словом

Сумма оплаты за товар/услугу, которая остаётся после предоставления скидки. Есть ли слово, которым можно выразить это значение?

Comment: Продажная цена? А цена без скидки - прейскурантная цена.

Comment: Если не "итог" (но это недостаточно точно), одним словом, видимо, не сказать...

Comment: Просто цена. Все остальные уточнения, это маркетинг от лукавого. Цена это то, что человек платит. Это общий смысл этого слова. *Цена его жизни была три копейки.* Сумма/число на ценнике, прайс со скидкой, без скидки - все это производные, дополнительные уточнения. Честным людям не требуются такие уточнения, цена есть цена.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Льготная цена** - пониженный уровень цены на товар в целях стимуляции продаж либо цена, дотируемая для отдельных групп покупателей

*Экономика и право: словарь-справочник. — М.: Вуз и школа. Л. П. Кураков, В. Л. Кураков, А. Л. Кураков. 2004.*

Comment: Прям представил, как прихожу в бутик "Луи Виттон", покупаю там что-либо со скидкой 10% и вижу в чеке: "Льготная цена..."

Comment: @Taosique, данный термин мне нужен для финансового приложения, в котором фигурировала именно льгота

Answer (score 8):

Слышала варианты:

- Цена со скидкой
- Окончательная цена
- Финальная цена
- Цена нетто

Одним словом не слышала.